# how to convert tinyMCE formatted html code back to regular html?

Tags: php, html, tinymce

I have some html code (formatted by tinyMCE) saved in my database. I want to use php to show those on my php. Can anyone help me do it ? Thanks.

Example tinyMCE formatted html code:

```
Chart+and+%2376+on+the+Billboard+Top+200%3CBR+%2F%3E--+The+album+%26quot%3BWild-Eyed+Dream%26quot%3B+has+been+certified+Platinum+by+the+RIAA+%3C%2FP%3E%3CP%3E%3CSTRONG%3EPlaque%3A+%3CBR+%2F%3E%3C%2FSTRONG%3EHigh+bidder+receives+one-of-a-kind+RIAA+certified+Platinum+album+with+handwritten+and+signed+lyrics.+%3C%2FP%3E
```

-
ahsan

Comment: Seems like URL encoded stuff.

Comment: tinyMCE does not url encode by default, so your doing it somewhere, better to remove that than fix it afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like php `urlencode`. try `urldecode`

Comment: thanks a lot, I had figured it out myself, a little while back. Thanks again.